# Total of cells formula for numbers as text

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to total up the numbers of split cells. I have an example as follows:

```
1234
0000
5678
```

each number is in its own cell, I want to total it all up underneath to get
6912, 
so 1234 + 0000 + 5678 = 6912 if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use **`SUMPRODUCT`** which is able to sum numbers acting like text strings:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(SPLIT(A1, " "))
  ```

  [image: 0]

  ---

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3)
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Cool thanks for that I will try it out